# SSRS/Sharepoint - Reports made in Report Builder not being list in Sharepoint Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs, tsql, webpart

I followed the steps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159772.aspx) to integrate reporting services with sharepoint in **native** mode.

I made a page in Sharepoint with the report explorer web part and everything is working.

The issue is when I create a report with the web based report builder tool, it **will** show up in the report manager page, but not show up in the report explorer web part on the share point page.

New reports I upload using report manager do show up.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I feel dumb.  There's a scroll bar on the right of the reports.  I just had to scroll down!

It's really hard to notice the scroll bar for some reason.